# How to make the capsule collider that comes with character controller follow the animations

Tags: unity, animation, bones

I'm making a 3D endless running game like subway surf. When I swipe/press down arrow the slide animation starts but the capsule collider isn't following along as it doesn't slides along with the character. Searched a lot on this on the forums, one possible answer is to attach the collider with some bone. I tried doing so, but couldn't make it. As I'm fairly new to Unity please provide some insights to how to overcome this situation. Here are the screen shots of the collider not following the sliding animation

[image: Image 1- Run Animation starting]

[image: Image 2- Sliding Animation Running with capsule collider standing uptight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a trick instead, just in case anybody else also has a similar problem: when the sliding animation starts I change the character controller's dimensions to just fit the slit. As soon as the sliding animation is over I reset the character controller's dimensions back to normal using the invoke method.

Comment: That's also what I would have done in an endless runner. In this genre you want full control over your hitboxes to keep the game predictable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try animating the collider as well.

Comment: I'm not aware, how to accomplish that; any help would be grateful.

Comment: Does your character have bones?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, as the character I'm using is 'Robot Kyle' which I downloaded from Unity Asset Store. I'm new to Unity and particularly not involved with character design and animation.